# construct a structured matrix efficiently in fortran

Tags: performance, matrix, fortran, fortran90

Having left Fortran for several years, now I have to pick it up and start to work with it again.

I'd like to construct a matrix with `entry(i,j)` in the form `f(x_i,y_j)`, where `f` is a function of two variables, e.g., `f(x,y)=cos(x-y)`. In Matlab or Python(Numpy), there are *efficient* ways to handle this kind of specific issue. I wonder whether there is such optimization in Fortran.

BTW, is it also true in Fortran that a vectorized operation is faster than a do/for loop (as is the case in Matlab and Numpy) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by vectorized the same as you mean in Matlab and Python, the short form you call on whole array then no, these forms are often slower, because they mey be harder to optimize than simple loops. What is faster is when the compiler actually uses the vector instructions of the CPU, but that is something else. And it is easier for the compiler to use them for simple loops.

Fortran has `elemental functions`, `do concurrent`, `forall` and `where` constructs, implied loops and array constructors. There is no point repeating them here, they have been described many times on this site or in tutorials.

Your example is most simply done using a loop

```
  do j = 1, ny
    do i = 1, nx
      entry(i,j) = f(x(i), y(j))
    end do
  end do
```

One of the short ways, you probably meant by Python-like vectorization, would be the whole-array operations, e.g.,

```
  A = cos(B)
  C = A * B
  D = f(A*B)
```

and similar. The function (which is called on each element of the array),  must be `elemental`. These operations are not necessarily efficient. For example, the last call may require a temporary array to be created, which would be avoided when using a loop.

Comment: Thank you. I knew every term well you mentioned when I was 3 or 4 years younger in college days. Now it is a bit disappointing that I have to start from zero again.